# I put this down to taught how to use grammar

Tags: grammar

I think this sounds horrible, but may be correct. Is it?

On the grounds that "I put this down to taught ability at grammar" sounds fine.

Comment: No, neither of those sentences sounds fine. They are both completely and utterly ungrammatical. _To_ as a preposition (like it is here) requires a noun phrase (including gerunds) as its object; _taught_ is a past participle. “To taught” is not English. I don’t even know what your sentence is trying to say: “I put it down to [someone’s] _having taught_ grammar”? “I put it down to [someone’s] _having been taught_ how to use grammar”?

Comment: Well, in the second, *taught* could be being used as an adjective (although how an ability can be taught might be debatable).

Comment: If *taught* is an adjective, then it should be the case *"I put this down to how to use grammar"* is correct. But it's not. And if *taught* is not an adjective, then the sentence is unambiguously wrong, because you can't put a past participle after *to*.

Comment: The quality or state of being able; capacity to do; capacity of doing something; having the necessary power. 

HTH ha ; )

Comment: @peter, can i use taught as the simple past there ?

Comment: You can't put the simple past after *to*, either.

Comment: are you sure? i haven't ever studied grammar, what meaning of "to" do you think is being used in "i put it down to"?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/down_to

Answer (score 2):

If you are a native speaker of English

> (you act like one, in having a preference for something that "sounds good"
>   --  and is in fact grammatical, if stilted -- and in never having studied grammar).

Then your instincts are good, but your intuition about how the parts go together is terrible.

> (If you are not a native speaker of English, I have to wonder where you're speaking it and to whom.)

- *I put this down to taught ability at grammar*

is not **quite** right -- "ability" *per se* can't be taught, though skills can be improved by practice --
but it's not an unreasonable thing to say, equivalent to

- *I attribute this **current ability of his** to

  **his having previously been** taught grammar

  **and his having learned it well enough to apply it**.*

*Taught grammar* would be grammar you learned at school.
Instead of grammar you already knew when you came to school because you could speak English.

So your instincts are right. But *taught grammar* is an idiom, like *store-bought bread*, and it can only extend in certain directions. *Grammar* is a noun, and a noun phrase, but one can't just swap it out at will for a headless relative infinitive clause noun phrase like *how to use grammar*.

There are in fact rules, and the rules are what is telling you it sounds terrible. I.e, ungrammatical.
As it's written, at least.

Comment: you can be taught an ability at something, if you had read the comments above you see that ability =/= innate ability. i'm not even sure you answered the question !

yes, i am a native english speaker

Comment: i will add that 'how' can be used as a noun, like 'ability' is

Comment: As in _He knows the how but not the why_?

Comment: i guess so... it still seems possible to me. 

at school, i was taught how / why to use grammar. this seems fine... the only difference is the extra information on who was taught and when/where. but it seems we can make explanations, without indicating who and when/where it happened. as in the OP "i put this down to taught ability at it"

Comment: Yes, you can make explanations, but you need to add the right preposition or article or auxiliary verb now and then to keep the accounting straight. [That's the rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf). Even the original sentence has been done things to. To say _He was taught grammar_ is to say _Somebody taught grammar to him_, so it's already undergone Dative Movement, promoting the indirect object to direct object (_Somebody taught him grammar_) before Passive promotes _him_ up be the subject of _was taught_. Whole lotta syntax goin on here.